# how to create Ag grid with multiple measures as row groups and formatting?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, tanstack

I am trying to create a proof of concept in React using Ag Grid Enterprise trial, but I cannot figure out way to create report in attached image. This is a typical finance report template with measures and dimensions in rows, and time periods in columns. The +/- sign refers to an expand/collapse feature.

Metrics are grouped into “metric_group”, and each metric can be drilled down to multiple levels starting from the product name. I have gone through the Ag Grid documentation and cannot figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me?

The columnDefs allows me select one aggregate method for all columns in pivot, but i need different aggregation and formatting based on the metric row.

```
 const columnDefs = [
        { field: 'metric_group', rowGroup: true,},
        { field: 'period',pivot: true},
        { field: 'metric',rowGroup: true,},
        { field: 'value', aggFunc: 'sum' }
    ];
```

[image]